# Can't create leaderboard in sandbox itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm trying to create a leaderboard for my game.  Unfortunately, after following iTunes connect's instructions and filling out the leaderboard and 1 language specification for the leaderboard, the Save Button simply refreshes the screen with the edit data but no leaderboard is created.

Am I out of my mind?  Am I missing a critical piece of information?

1) Created bundle App Id
2) Created App in iTunes Connect
3) Enabled Game Center
4) Went to Game Center to edit leaderboards
5) Add New Leaderboard (Single Leaderboard)
6) Fill out form
7) All aboard the fail boat. (Does not actually save and create the leaderboard but just refreshes the page)

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this...
I had the same greyed out 'save' button and the reason was that i have only set the minimal value for the leaderboard score and left the maximum empty. I was under the impression that the number displayed below the box means it will be used. I had to copy it into the box and it fixed the problem.

Damn Apple could add some opoup/tip to that page

Comment: I do exactly the same. I think that the number below max score will be used :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  Apparently you can't have a dash in your leaderboard name.  However, no error comes up in the dialog.  Bah!